# How to compare the value of two fields in Kibana

Tags: dsl, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I have two kinds of logs in ES (rtmp and apache), apache has clientip.raw and rtmp has ipclient.raw. The problem is: how can I see in my Kibana panel just the data that has this condition "ipclient"="clientip" ?

I tried writing this in my search bar, but doesn´t work:

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "script": {"script": "doc['clientip.raw'].value == doc['ipclient.raw'].value"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the below query:-

```
{"constant_score":{"filter":{"script" : { "script" : "doc['clientip.raw'].value == doc['ipclient.raw'].value"}}}}
```

You may see an error while using above query such as:-

> ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]

To solve this error, edit your elasticsearch.yml file and enter the following property at the end:-

```
 script.inline:on
```

Then you can restart your Elasticsearch node or cluster and then query the same on Kibana which will fetch you desired records.

Comment: Hi! First thanks for your answer, but It doesn't work, the error appears and in my elasticsearch.yml I have put this configuration :    script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true
 script.engine.groovy.file.search: true
 script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
 script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
 script.search: on
 script.indexed: on
 script.inline: on

Comment: Just put script.inline:on at the end , remove every other property as mentioned by you and restart your elasticsearch node. Also check after restarting if elasticsearch is working or not. If elasticsearch starts properly after adding this property then it will work in Kibana as well.

Comment: The script works, but I don´t get the records that meet the condition... =S

Comment: I have verified at my end and I am able to find the records that meets the condition.

Comment: Could be a mapping problem?

Comment: Does both of the fields have same data type?

Comment: Yes: `"clientip" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "norms" : {
              "enabled" : false
            },
            "fielddata" : {
              "format" : "disabled"
            },
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }` ipclient has the same.

Comment: where should I apply the above query? I applied in script field but it throws `Failed to parse expression`